# SDL2 program write only part of string

Tags: c++, sdl-2, truetype

I have a code with a function `TextOut` that writes one char on the window every time with some delay. All was in normal but my program writes only part of string to the window. However sometimes program writes the whole text.

This function create wchar from char

```
char* cts(char c)
{
    char *ptr = (char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    ptr[0] = c;
    ptr[1] = '\0';
    return ptr;
}



void TextOut(SDL_Renderer *ren, TTF_Font *f)
{
    SDL_Surface *sur;
    SDL_Texture *tex;
    static SDL_Rect rect;
    static int32_t x;

   //Checking if string is end  
    if (OUT_STRING[x] == '\0') return;

    //Get a wide char from string 
    char *temp = cts(OUT_STRING[x]);

    //Get the size of font
    TTF_SizeText(f, temp, &rect.w, &rect.h);

    sur = TTF_RenderText_Blended(f, temp, color)

    free(temp);

    tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, sur);
    SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tex, NULL, &rect);
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    rect.x += rect.w;
    x++;
    SDL_FreeSurface(sur);
    SDL_Delay(50);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    /*

    Initialization of Window, Renderer, Font and other things

    */

    OUT_STRING = "We are waiting";


    while (!quit)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
        {
            TextOut(renderer, font);
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) quit = true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I realized that the program still outputs the required text but after a certain amount of the main cycle pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you describe is due to your event loop - you're calling your render function there. When your window is shown, several events are generated (SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED, etc.), so your render function called severnal times, but not enough for your "whole" text. When more events arrives (mouse move, keypressed, window manipulations, ...) - you can see more. If that is undesired behaviour - you should use event loop for what it is, events handling, e.g.:

```
while (!quit)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
    {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) quit = true;
    }
    TextOut(renderer, font);
}
```

It is questionable how you're going to continue drawing after all characters are shown, or why you need malloc (you don't).

Comment: Problem is solwed. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the whole text appeared invariably so I haven't been able to test if these improvements will solve your problem or not, but they are definitely issues with your code.

You should free the memory allocated by the `malloc` inside `cts`, for example you can do it like this:

```
char* temp = cts(OUT_STRING[x]);
TTF_SizeText(f, temp, &rect.w, &rect.h);
free(temp);
```

When checking if an exit event has happened, don't use assignment instead of comparison. The correct way to do this is:

```
if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) quit = true;
```

When checking if you have reached the end of the `char` array, don't use `NULL`. Do it like this instead:

```
if (OUT_STRING[x] == '\0') return;
```

Comment: You're welcome. There is no such thing as a stupid mistake, as long as you learn from it ;)

Comment: If you want to get your already working code checked, please don't post it here, but on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).